# How can I delete or ignore a test when compiling vim?

Tags: compile-vim, linux-arch

I am compiling vim under Arch linux and it is failing the test "test_netbeans.vim" even though I did not ask for netbeans to be enabled for the build.

I tried editing the shared.vim file and removing the test files but it does not work because the compilation system apparently rewrites the test files every time it compiles.

How can I either ignore the test or delete it?

Comment: Is there maybe a flag to disable netbeans (during the configure step)? It may be enabled by default (?).

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this problem by using the compile switch:

```
--disable-netbeans
```

However, obviously it is just a workaround and the test failure will be a problem for anyone that wants to use netbeans with compiled vim.

Comment: I just compiled 8.1.722 on Ubuntu 16.04. Netbean integration is enabled by default. The test_netbeans.vim was run and OK.

Comment: Probably because it is Ubuntu. Arch has messed up python configuration and vim is not tested against Arch so its tests are broken on Arch.